# Using YAML and Images from a single directory in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have a Jekyll-based and Github-pages-hosted site. I also have a Git Submodule that contains both YAML files and images. I would like to use it within my GitHub pages Jekyll project but I’m not sure how.

Here's example directory structure:

```
/assets/
/_data/
/MyGitSubmodule/yaml/
/MyGitSubmodule/images/
```

I’m used to putting YAML files in `_data` and images in `/assets/`. Is there a way to configure Jekyll *also* parse YAML files in another directory? Or copy static files from somewhere in `_data` during the build step? Or set up symlinks? That work with GitHub Pages?

I've tried:

- Changing the `data_dir` setting to be the same as my `/assets/` directory but I don't want to make my data files publicly accessible.
- Creating a symbolic link on Windows with `mklink /D` but I get an error on serving`C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:141:in` initialize': Is a directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Ben/personalsite2/assets/unreal/specifiers (Errno::EISDIR)`. Also ]this page seems to imply that they work on GitHub pages](https://github.com/chetabahana/symlink) but other docs for Jekyll seem to say that they are disabled in “safe mode” and GitHub pages.

Answer (score 1):

Eh in the end I solved this by putting my `data_dir` inside `/assets/` and by by using the `exclude` setting in `config.yml` to stop it from serving some of the yml files